# ajax GET/POST, what is actually being sent?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'somewhere.php',
    data: { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' }
});
```

I know that this would generate a get-string in firebug, similar to `somepage.php?foo=foo&bar=bar`

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'somewhere.php',
    data: { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' },
    type: 'POST'
});
```

And this would post a form with the values.

But is it a complete page that is being sent when using `$.ajax()`? Or is it just parts of a page?

Comment: In both cases you are sending an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end it's just another HTTP request being sent. The parameters of your `$.ajax()` call define what the request looks like. You're not sending a page, much like you're not sending a page when you tell your browser to visit google.com by typing it in the address bar.

You are receiving a page, though. The difference between receiving a page via an ajax call and browsing to it is that it's not sent to your browser's render engine and displayed in its own window or tab, but the source of that page is simply sent to the callback functions you define in jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

`data` parameter contains all the data you are sending, so it is not part of the page nor whole page (unless you make it so).

In your example you are sending two variables `foo` and `bar`, which are inside object, only difference here is method (`get` or `post`) of sending your data.

Comment: SO what would be the difference between sending an ajax get and a post? I dont see any reason to use a get.

Comment: Well, then, much have been said about `GET` vs `POST` e.g. [Get vs Post for the beginner](http://stevenclark.com.au/2008/01/12/get-vs-post-for-the-beginner/)

Comment: So it seems that you need to figure when to use `get` and when to use `post`, also I've found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399105/get-and-post-method-in-html)